# redirect to localhost using iptables

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I'd like to redirect the outgoing traffic (whether coming from localhost or elsewhere, as the machine is a gateway) going from `192.168.0.2:80` to `localhost:80`.

I've tried setting this rule in the nat table:

```
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.0.2 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:80
```

And I end up with the following rule, when I type `iptables -t nat -L`:

```
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.0.2          tcp dpt:http to:127.0.0.1:80
```

But this does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: That rule is good looking, have you enabled the `net.ip4.ip_forward`? set it to 1 in `/etc/sysctl.conf`

Answer (score 4):

On newer kernels this can be achieved by enabling "route_localnet"

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet=1
```

Comment: perfect! just what i was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Try double checking that your loopback ip address (127.0.0.1) is setup to reach `localhost`. Ping both to make sure they both get a good response under:

```
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

1. Look at your iptables:

   `sudo iptables -L -n`
2. Try adding this rule with

   `iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -d 192.168.0.2 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:80`